# How can I get a full width html email in gmail with text?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

The below images (Scenario A, Scenario B) are taken from GMAIL app for same newsletter. The only difference is the highlighted portion in Scenario B is an image. Ideally I want scenario B (its properly aligned and takes 600 px width), but how can I achieve it with text itself (as shown in Scenario A)?

The problem I am facing is its getting wrapped like a mobile layout and because of that the whole template width is getting reduced.

[Scenario A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x88OF.png) [Scenario B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9iLZ.png)

The difference in code for Scenario A & Scenario B

**Scenario A:**

---

```
<div style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding:0;margin:0 auto;width:100%!important"> 
<div style="overflow:hidden;color:transparent;width:0;font-size:0;min-height:0">
</div> 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" border="0" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td align="center"> 
                <center style="width:100%">   
                    <table width="580" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:580px; width:inherit; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"> 
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                                <td width="100%" bgcolor="#F3F3F3" style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #ececec"> 
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-weight:200;width:100%!important;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;min-width:100%!important"> 
                                        <tbody> 
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="47%" valign="middle">
                                                   <div>
                                                      <a target="_blank" title="MyTechLogy" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/"><img src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/view/images/MyTechLogy-Logo-TagLine-200.png" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;outline:none;text-decoration:none" title="MyTechLogy" alt="MyTechLogy"></a>
                                                   </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left" width="47%" valign="middle" style="padding:10px 0 10px 20px">
                                                  <div>
                                                      <img src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/upload/by_users/Bharath/241605103728ITcareerdevelopment.png" border="0" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; height:60px;" title="Your Online Professional IT Career Development Platform." alt="Your Online Professional IT Career Development Platform.">
                                                   </div> 
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody> 
                                    </table>
                                </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#29acc8" align="center" width="580">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                            <td width="100%" height="30" style="padding-left: 20px; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#ffffff;line-height:20px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;"><strong><span style="text-align:left;">Weekly Highlights from the Analytics Corner</span></strong></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#29acc8; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                <strong><a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/11037/how-to-ace-your-data-analytics-interview/" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color:#29acc8;">Tips to ace your Data Analytics Interview</span></a></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">  
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:20px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                I test drove the new Career Initiative feature at MyTechlogy and was pretty impressed by the kind of insights it threw up overnight. I think young professionals in data analytics or data science will find it helpful if they're looking for data that will help them make a decision about their own careers.. <a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/11037/how-to-ace-your-data-analytics-interview/"style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#29acc8;">Read more >></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#29acc8; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                <strong><span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:28px;">Career Switch to Analytics?</span> <span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:28px;"><a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color:#29acc8;">See which IT skills can help you get there >></span></a></span></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" width="560">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10" ></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:20px;">
                                    <div align="center">    
                                        <table align="center" valign="middle" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td width="560px" align="left" valign="middle" height="60" style=" text-align:left; background-color:#29acc8; font-size:21px; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;  color:#ffffff; font-weight: 300; padding-left:10px;">
                                                   <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400;text-align:left">
                                                      <strong>IT Career Progression made easier with MyTechLogy</strong>
                                                   </span>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </div>  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" width="560">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">  
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:20px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                MyTechlogy provides personalized insights from industry data to help you stay relevant and to progress your IT career.
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                       <a target="_blank" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes"><img width="540" border="0" height="163" alt="IT career progression has been made easier with MyTechLogy" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/upload/by_users/Bharath/181605050426CareerProgression.png" class="bigimage"></a>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                            </tr>   

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div align="center">    
                                        <a style="color: #ffffff; text-align:center;text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes">
                                            <table height="60" align="center" valign="middle" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablet-button" st-button="edit">
                                              <tbody>
                                                 <tr align="center">
                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" height="60" style=" background-color:#FF6600; border-top-left-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px;border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; background-clip: padding-box;font-size:22px; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;  color:#ffffff; font-weight: 300; padding-left:18px; padding-right:18px; box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px #888888;">

                                                       <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400;">
                                                          <a style="color: #ffffff; text-align:center;text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes"><strong>Create your Career Initiative Now!</strong></a>
                                                       </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                 </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                           </table>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#29acc8" align="center" width="580">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" align="center" width="580">
                                        <tbody>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#666666;line-height:15px; padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                                                   <div style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding-top:20px;margin:0 auto;width:100%!important"> 
                                                   To unsubscribe from receiving this email into future, click <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0db9ea" href="[UNSUBSCRIBEURL]">unsubscribe</a> </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody> 
                    </table> 
                </center>
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

---

**Scenario B:**

---

```
<div style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding:0;margin:0 auto;width:100%!important"> 
<div style="overflow:hidden;color:transparent;width:0;font-size:0;min-height:0">
</div> 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" border="0" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td align="center"> 
                <center style="width:100%">   
                    <table width="580" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:580px; width:inherit; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"> 
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                                <td width="100%" bgcolor="#F3F3F3" style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #ececec"> 
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-weight:200;width:100%!important;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;min-width:100%!important"> 
                                        <tbody> 
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="47%" valign="middle">
                                                   <div>
                                                      <a target="_blank" title="MyTechLogy" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/"><img src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/view/images/MyTechLogy-Logo-TagLine-200.png" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;outline:none;text-decoration:none" title="MyTechLogy" alt="MyTechLogy"></a>
                                                   </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left" width="340" valign="middle" style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px">
                                                  <div> <span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#333333; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle;">Your Online Professional<br />IT Career Development Platform.</span>
                                                   </div> 
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody> 
                                    </table>
                                </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#29acc8" align="center" width="580">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                            <td width="100%" height="30" style="padding-left: 20px; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#ffffff;line-height:20px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;"><strong><span style="text-align:left;">Weekly Highlights from the Analytics Corner</span></strong></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#29acc8; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                <strong><a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/11037/how-to-ace-your-data-analytics-interview/" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color:#29acc8;">Tips to ace your Data Analytics Interview</span></a></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">  
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:20px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                I test drove the new Career Initiative feature at MyTechlogy and was pretty impressed by the kind of insights it threw up overnight. I think young professionals in data analytics or data science will find it helpful if they're looking for data that will help them make a decision about their own careers.. <a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/11037/how-to-ace-your-data-analytics-interview/"style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#29acc8;">Read more >></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#29acc8; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                <strong><span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:28px;">Career Switch to Analytics?</span> <span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:28px;"><a href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color:#29acc8;">See which IT skills can help you get there >></span></a></span></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" width="560">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10" ></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:20px;">
                                    <div align="center">    
                                        <table align="center" valign="middle" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td width="560px" align="left" valign="middle" height="60" style=" text-align:left; background-color:#29acc8; font-size:21px; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;  color:#ffffff; font-weight: 300; padding-left:10px;">
                                                   <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400;text-align:left">
                                                      <strong>IT Career Progression made easier with MyTechLogy</strong>
                                                   </span>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </div>  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" width="560">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">  
                                <td align="left" width="560" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:20px; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px">
                                MyTechlogy provides personalized insights from industry data to help you stay relevant and to progress your IT career.
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; ">
                                       <a target="_blank" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes"><img width="540" border="0" height="163" alt="IT career progression has been made easier with MyTechLogy" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/upload/by_users/Bharath/181605050426CareerProgression.png" class="bigimage"></a>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                            </tr>   

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div align="center">    
                                        <a style="color: #ffffff; text-align:center;text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes">
                                            <table height="60" align="center" valign="middle" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablet-button" st-button="edit">
                                              <tbody>
                                                 <tr align="center">
                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" height="60" style=" background-color:#FF6600; border-top-left-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px;border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; background-clip: padding-box;font-size:22px; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;  color:#ffffff; font-weight: 300; padding-left:18px; padding-right:18px; box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px #888888;">

                                                       <span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400;">
                                                          <a style="color: #ffffff; text-align:center;text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.mytechlogy.com/my-page/?create_initiative=yes"><strong>Create your Career Initiative Now!</strong></a>
                                                       </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                 </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                           </table>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#29acc8" align="center" width="580">
                                      <tbody>
                                         <tr valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                            <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" align="center" width="580">
                                        <tbody>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#666666;line-height:15px; padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                                                   <div style="background-color:#f6f4f5;padding-top:20px;margin:0 auto;width:100%!important"> 
                                                   To unsubscribe from receiving this email into future, click <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0db9ea" href="[UNSUBSCRIBEURL]">unsubscribe</a> </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody> 
                    </table> 
                </center>
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

---

Please help how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

These td's should be placed within a table that's 600px wide and thát one should be placed within a table that's 100% wide.
Hope this helps. Otherwise, please post more of your code, so we can adjust it.

Comment: I have updated the code above for your reference. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

please use following code:

```
<table align=center" width="100%">
            <td align="left" width="48%" valign="middle" style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#333333; line-height:28px; vertical-align:middle;">
    Your Online Professional<br />IT Career Development Platform.
    </td>
<td align="left" width="48%" valign="middle" style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px"><img src="http://www.mytechlogy.com/upload/by_users/Bharath/241605103728ITcareerdevelopment.png" border="0" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; height:60px;" title="Your Online Professional IT Career Development Platform." alt="Your Online Professional IT Career Development Platform."></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It didn't work. The result is still the same in gmail mobile app.